# how to removr last trail slash from third column in a text with notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Example:

Redirect 301 /url1/ https://www.website.com/page1/

must be

Redirect 301 /url1 https://www.website.com/page1/

thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: - [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: Would replacing `/ ` (slash followed by space) with an single space suffice? You can do that with a standard search and replace and no need for any magic regexes.